# Thread Creation - is it dynamically allocated?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, pthreads

Is a thread dynamically allocated memory?

I have been researching and have a fair understanding of threads and how they are used. I have specifically looked at the POSIX API for threads.

I am trying to understand thread creation and how it differs from a simple malloc call.

I understand that threads share certain memory segments with the parent process, but it has it's own stack.

Any resources I can read through on this topic is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you can see [this](https://gist.github.com/jbwyme/9479813) about pthread local storage. pthread run functions as thread so each thread has it's own stack.

Comment: A thread has more than just memory. Usually a thread is associated with operating system data (if it is associated with an OS task). A thread can be joined with (yielding its return value). A thread can be signaled or canceled.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything. Im kind of curious if a malloc is used in thread creation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thread creation and a malloc() call are completely different concepts. A malloc() call dynamically allocates the requested byte chunk of memory from the heap for the use of the program.

Whereas a thread can be considered as a 'light-weight process'. The thread is an entity within a process and every process will have atleast one thread to help complete its execution. The threads of a process will share the process virtual address and all the resources of the process. When you create new threads of a process, these new threads will have their own user stack, they will be scheduled independently to be executed by the scheduler. Also for the thread to run concurrently they will have their context which will store the state of the thread just before preemption i.e the status of all the registers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a thread dynamically allocated memory?

No, nothing of the sort.  Threads have memory uniquely associated with them -- at least a stack -- but such memory is not the thread itself.

> I am trying to understand thread creation and how it differs from a simple malloc call.

New thread creation is not even the same *kind* of thing as memory allocation.  The two are not at all comparable.

Threading implementations that have direct OS support (not all do) are unlikely to rely on the C library to obtain memory for their stack, kernel data structures, or any other thread-implementation-associated data.  On the other hand, those that do not have OS support, such as Linux's old "green" threads, are more likely to allocate memory via the C library.  Even threading implementations without direct OS support have the option of using a system call to obtain the memory they need, just as `malloc()` itself must do.  In any case, the memory obtained is not itself the thread.

Note also that the difference between threading systems with and without OS support is orthogonal to the threading API.  For example, Linux's green threads and the now-ubiquitous, kernel-supported NPTL threads both implement the POSIX thread API.